# How to manage data for SQL Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database, entity-relationship

I have questions about SQL database. I'm not sure that this problem is called "Load balancer".

I'm designing database to record the data from device. There are 5 tables. Each table will be received data every 5 min.
The total per month are 10,000,000 rows/month for one table. This is the problem because the data in database will continuously increase. I would like to know what the solution to solve this problem.

Please suggest to me.

Comment: You give us very little to go on. Do you want/need to store all data indefinitely? Do you want to archive old or irrelevant data? Do you want to delete old or irrelevant data?
It's also necessary to understand how much data you think is ok and when does it become too much?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I want to store all data for last 5 years but I'm not sure that SQL database can store a lot data like this.

Comment: Azure SQL can store [enormous amount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale?view=azuresql#what-are-the-hyperscale-capabilities) of data depending on tier you choose and the design of your database.

With that amount of data ingestion, it's a good thing to make it as easy for the db to manage as possible and from the start. I would start by choosing an appropriate compression technique if you have not already done that. With compression you will lessen the storage burden as well as increase the speed of your queries.

Comment: To determine which compression to choose it would be good to understand:
- if you need to update data or are you only inserting new data?
- How will the data be used? (Reporting? Analytics?)

The compression techniques to choose from is [page compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-ver16) or [Clustered Columnstore Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16).